# Python Scrapy Response 200 but Javascript content not loading

Tags: python, scrapy

I can send a GET request to the main page (in start_urls) with the correct header, my __RequestVerificationToken is working and I can see the response content of the main page. But I do not see any content data of the subpages, the response is 200 but the content is just the plain HTML page source not containing the dynamically loaded content. Seems like that a subpage is detecting Scrapy as a bot.

My Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import json
import time

class eva_db_spider(scrapy.Spider): 
    name = 'eva'
    custom_settings = {
        #'DEPTH_PRIORITY': 0,
        #'SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue',
        #'SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue',
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
        'COOKIES_ENABLED': True
    }

    start_urls = ['https://bieterportal.noncd.db.de/evergabe.bieter/eva/supplierportal/portal/tabs/vergaben']

    def parse(self, response):
        mainpage_100items = 'https://bieterportal.noncd.db.de/evergabe.bieter/api/supplier/project/publicProjects?cultureName=de-DE&pageIndex=0&pageSize=100&sortExpression=publicationDate%20desc'

        # extract token from page source
        token = response.xpath('/html/head/script[1]').get()
        if 'auth_token' in token:
            token = token[26:211]
            # print('__RequestVerificationToken = ' + token)
        else:
            print('Token not found')
            # logic for informing user + quit script

        self.headers = {
            'Host': 'bieterportal.noncd.db.de',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Referer': 'https://bieterportal.noncd.db.de/evergabe.bieter/eva/supplierportal/portal/tabs/vergaben',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            '__RequestVerificationToken': token
        }

        yield scrapy.Request(mainpage_100items, callback=self.parse_identifier_for_subpage, headers=self.headers)


    def parse_identifier_for_subpage(self, response):    
        raw_data = response.text
        data = json.loads(raw_data)
        for item in data['projects']:
            identifier_in_url = item['identifier']
            subpage = f'https://bieterportal.noncd.db.de/evergabe.bieter/eva/supplierportal/portal/subproject/{identifier_in_url}/details'
            request = scrapy.Request(subpage, callback=self.parse_subpage, headers=self.headers)
            time.sleep(0.05)

            yield request

    def parse_subpage(self, response):
        raw_data = response.text # Output plain page source, no content
        print('+++ Subpage Content Start +++')
        print(raw_data)
        test = input('+++ Subpage Content End +++ \nPress ENTER to see the next subpage...')
        
process = CrawlerProcess(settings = {
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'
})

process.crawl(eva_db_spider)
process.start()
```

Output:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="de-DE"><head><base href="/evergabe.bieter/ClientUI.2/dist/"/><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><title>eVa 4.9 Healy Hudson - Supplier</title><meta name="description" content="eVa 4.9 Healy Hudson - Supplier"><script>var auth_token = \'<A...token...will...be...visible...here...as...soon...as...you...visit...the...page>\';\r\n        var baseAppPath = \'/evergabe.bieter\';\r\n        var copyright = \'&copy; 2021 Healy Hudson GmbH\';\r\n        var version = \'4.9.21.120\';</script><!-- Configured Head Tags  --><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="32x32" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico"><meta name="theme-color" content="#00bcd4"><!-- CSS will be injected by webpack here --><!-- Preload link tags will be injected by webpack here --><link href="vendor-main-b56c880e29d6fe6f0b60.css" rel="stylesheet"/><link href="main-73909145cca1a58643f2.css" rel="stylesheet"/><link rel="preload" href="vendor-main-polyfills.4be5abd490d0ad562c3e.chunk.js" as="script"/><link rel="preload" href="vendor-main.b56c880e29d6fe6f0b60.chunk.js" as="script"/><link rel="preload" href="vendor-polyfills.ee836bc0219a916f40d3.chunk.js" as="script"/><link rel="preload" href="polyfills.86ff653bff363d3ebeee.chunk.js" as="script"/><link rel="preload" href="main.73909145cca1a58643f2.chunk.js" as="script"/></head><body><app><!-- loading spinner layout replaced by app after startup --><div class="app-loading"><svg class="spinner" viewBox="25 25 50 50"><circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"></circle></svg></div></app><!-- Scripts will be injected by webpack here --><script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.cc477948046220dba513.bundle.js" async></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor-main-polyfills.4be5abd490d0ad562c3e.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor-main.b56c880e29d6fe6f0b60.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor-polyfills.ee836bc0219a916f40d3.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.86ff653bff363d3ebeee.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.73909145cca1a58643f2.chunk.js" async></script></body></html>'
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy does not include a javascript engine, if you need to access dynamically loaded content the scrapy documentation offers some tips. I would recommend using scrapy-splash but if performance is a priority requirement I would try to replicate the request that loads the dynamic
content.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: Thanks. Performance is not an issue. Please note, I'm still getting the dynamically loaded content from the initial url only by providing a correct header with a valid token - without using scrapy-splash. But when Scrapy is trying to access a nested page then something is going wrong and the response is a plain page with 200 OK, no data.

Comment: I debugged your code but from mainpage_100items I only get content that is not dynamically loaded. your xpath selector /html/head/script[1] works because it is selecting a static script.

Comment: if you really don't care about performance you could even use selenium

Comment: thanks a lot, LuisA310. Selenium was my last option :-) Anyway, when I open the browser, disable Javascript and try to open the start_urls page then an empty page appears - so that means there is no static script... Scrapy gets besides the xpath('/html/head/script[1]') all other data from the initial page. Output from "data = json.loads(raw_data)" is {'totalCount': 265, 'projects': [{'identifier': 'bee91e9a-81da-4df3-89a1-bccc9e2d70af', 'projectNumber': '21FEI52645', 'info': 'Sicherungsleistungen; [...] This Output is dynamic, isn't it?